# Who is The Fulcrum?

Tags: comics, marvel, powers

The Fulcrum is considered [The One-Above-All](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gods_%28Marvel_Comics%29#The_.22One-Above-All.22). The [Dreaming Celestial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreaming_Celestial) stated that:

> "Every component in the physical Universe is a model/example/function of balance... Every particle/being/concept/action exists in this state of sublime equilibrium to serve [a being known as] the Fulcrum."

Is this true? And, if so, is there any prove of it? 
Are his Powers and Abilities known or ever shown? 
And the most important thing, how come he [runs a bar where the Eternals hang out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fulcrum_%28comics%29) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Fulcrum is known by a variety of names in the Marvel multiverse, his/her/its/their other name is The One-Above-All.**

[image]

As the supreme being of the Omniverse, the One-Above-All is Omnipotent, Omnipresent, Omniscient and Omniversal, infinitely above all cosmic powers and abstract entities, even the [Living Tribunal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_Tribunal), who is the mightiest force in the Marvel Universe, a being capable of altering our reality at will.

> Apparently responsible for the existence of all life in the Multiverse and possibly beyond, the One-Above-All is the master and sole superior of the cosmic overseer and arbitrator known as the Living Tribunal. [--Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/One-Above-All_%28Multiverse%29)

Marvel has danced with the idea of talking about a supreme being of the multiverse for decades having teased us with images of God. They occasionally would break the [Fourth Wall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_wall) and show us the comic creators as the ultimate creators of the comic stories.

[image]

Ultimately, The One-Above-All had to come into play once the Cosmic Entities showed up on stage on a regular basis. With stories like the battles over the [Cosmic Cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_Cube), The Secret Wars (with [the Beyonder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyonder)) and [Infinity Gauntlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infinity_Gauntlet) peeling back the true nature of the universe, there had to be a representative force preventing such events from destroying the Mainstream Marvel Universe (Earth #616).

The [Cosmic Entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_entity_%28Marvel_Comics%29) fulfill the role of an [immune system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immune_system) for the Universe and the One-Above-All represents a final arbiter of all things, everywhere, every-when. Despite being the final arbiter, the One-Above-All is almost never depicted in the same light as other cosmic entities, it is instead portrayed as something benign, beyond malice, understanding of the frailties of mortal beings. Though, he is not above using agents do what needs to be done.

> - Thanos realizes that the One-Above-All has subtly manipulated him into destroying and recreating the Universe using its Heart in order to fix a fundamental flaw.
> - A being claiming to be the One-Above-All appeared to the Fantastic Four in "Heaven", at the time of the Thing's death, praising them for their persistence in exploring the Marvel Universe and promising extraordinary new wonders to be discovered in the years ahead, and eventually restores the Thing back to life.
> - A grieving Peter Parker was encouraged by the One-Above-All, disguised as an elderly homeless man, to keep faith, when his Aunt May lay close to death.
> - When a bartender asks the demon Mephisto whether the Living Tribunal, having created the Infinite Embassy, was actually "God", Mephisto responds, "No, he's not God. He's just the biggest kid in all the playgrounds. And if he knows the Principal, he's not exactly chatty about it."

As to why a bar for Eternals or anyone else that shows up? Why not? You can be sure at his bar, everyone really knows your name.

---

The One-Above-All is not to be confused with the Celestial (a race of cosmically powered entities who perform genetic experiments on planets through out the universe) who is also called [The One Above All](http://marvel.com/universe/One_Above_All_%28Celestial%29). He is also called The Prime Celestial. (upper left corner of the graphic in blue)

[image]

Comment: So, despite those examples you give, does he ever proves to be HIM? I mean, how do we know that the One-Above-All is the elderly homeless man disguised? I must admit that I'm not a Comic Reader, perhaps I'm losing something obvious on how this kind of info is given? Does he ever, clearly, shows he's omnipotence? And for the bar thing, how is it known that He is the one who runs it? I love the idea, by the way! Its like Terry Pratchett's, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, the One-Above-All is a concept that goes way, way back in the cosmic Marvel, just often overlooked or misinterpreted. Basically, this being is the Living Tribunal's master. The details? Vague. But then again, so it is with every Universe's Supreme Being, even this one...